# An OSGi use case - am I right or not?

Tags: java, osgi, architecture, modularization

I am just familiar with OSGi technology - never used but heard of it so many times. I've read several articles "for dummies" but I think I still fail to understand its use case completely. Maybe some of you could confirm if I understood it correctly.

Here is an example of what I might want to do.
Let us assume that I want to build a Java web application. Simple war. But, organized in such way that it contains different modules. Each module would contain different functionalities. Maybe each module would be packed as a separate jar, I am not sure.

Now, what I would like to have is UI part of the app capable of checking which of the modules are deployed too in order to show (or not) related menus, items, parts of pages, etc...

So, is the OSGi technology solution for this kind of problems or not? Is this what it is intended to be used for or am I off the track?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OSGi technology is a solution for the kind of problem you mentioned in your question.

Eclipse is one solution that uses OSGi technology.  In Eclipse, the UI would be an Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP), while the other modules would be Eclipse plug-ins.  Each module would be a separate package that includes more components than a JAR.

You can use other solution platforms, or write all of the OSGi code yourself.  The idea behind OSGi is to make your application more modular, so that you can update pieces of your application without having to update the entire application.

Comment: Ok, I am aware that eclipse is using OSGi, I was wondering if similar can be done with web pages.
Should I place pages that use functionalities from a module into that module also, or I would have to put them straight to the war?

It would be really awesome if module could bring not only new functionalities but also a part of UI. In that case my UI (the core of it) would be always the same - module would add more UI content on top of it. Is this possible to do?

Comment: @ezamur: For web pages, you have a Java application server like Glassfish or Websphere.  OSGi technology provides an application or function server for other types of applications.

Comment: @ezamur: The JBoss application server, yes.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for your answers.
Do you know maybe where I could inform my self more on this subject?
Not OSGi, but this specific problem I described.

Comment: @ezamur: You want to look up Java Servlets, Java Server Pages (JSP) or Java Server Faces (JSF), and Java Enterprise Edition (JEE).  Downloading and installing the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers will be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I am not that unfamiliar with the stuff :) I thought something more as an example. Thank you again, I will find something useful, I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is the OSGi technology solution for this kind of problems or not? Is this what it is intended to be used for or am I of the track?

I would say this is exactly the kind of scenario OSGi caters for.

Look into the [Eclipse RAP project](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/), which runs on top of the [Equinox OSGI container](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/), and does the kind of thing you describe.

Some excellent tutorials are available on [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html).

Comment: I just checked the link you provided, it looks really interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20Modular%20Vaadin%20Application%20with%20OSGi;jsessionid=64C2FA38BC97794ACB5A78F231D3428F) is an osgi based web framework in which you can accomplish this.
Alternatively you could have a look at the [OSGI and Equinox](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FOSGi-Equinox-Creating-Modular-Systems%2Fdp%2F0321585712&rct=j&q=osgi%20book&ei=AvPfTZ-gJcntOfqf8YEK&usg=AFQjCNEu4mmqAWtz-4vDZ5yg3oXqR84yNw) book, it should contain enough info to help you roll your own solution.

Comment: Thank you, user424935. Vaading is exactly what I ran into after some investigation. It will probably be the way to do.